# sending logs to splunk between docker containers

Tags: docker, logging, java

I have an app that runs in a docker container (say A). The app includes a log4j2 yaml configuration file, which has an Http_Appender routing logs to http://host.docker.internal:8080/log ready to be received in a proxy in docker container B. These logs are then setup to be queued to a websocket server at localhost:8080.

How might I configure the proxy to not only output to a websocket but also to splunk enterprise, where queries for the app take in stuff like the proxy name in java